# Linux & Php : server with MySQL database with terminal

Tags: php, mysql, linux

Hello I'm new in Linux and sorry if this subject already exist,

I know that with php and Linux you can start a local server with the commande

```
php -S 127.0.0.1:8080
```

I just wanted to know if we can work with a local database in this way with Linux

PS: I don't want to install Xampp

Comment: Yes you can. You just need to install mysql database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, you can install an local MySQL Server. If you are running Ubuntu/Debian here we go:

Install MySQL and PHP Modules

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-server php5-mysql
```

Finish Setup with:

```
sudo /usr/bin/mysql_secure_installation
```

Thats it!